# Issue Retrieving a Screenshot from a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, orm

I've got a bunch of screenshots and some screenshot meta data I'm trying to display in an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application, I'm trying to retrieve the data from my databse but I get this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Drawing.Image
>   ByteArrayToImage(Byte[])' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

Here's my code:

```
    var screenshotData = (from screenshots in db.screenshots
                              where screenshots.projects_ID == projectID
                              select new ImageInformation
                              {
                                  ID = screenshots.id,
                                  Language = screenshots.language,
                                  Screenshot = Utility.ByteArrayToImage(screenshots.screen_shot),
                                  ProjectID = screenshots.projects_ID
                              });

    foreach (ImageInformation info in screenshotData)
    {
        this.Add(info);
    }
```

ImageInformation is just a simple class that contains the defintion the information stored (ID, Language, Screenshot, ProjectID).

Here's my ByteArrayToImage function:

```
public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
    {
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me why I receive this error when this code runs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because, with LINQ-to-Entities, the code is turned into server-side query and it can't do that in this case.  I don't think you can mix client-side code like this directly with L2E.

I would suspect you will have to do the conversion from byte->image after you've retrieved the data from the database as a distinct step.

Comment: Weird, this works with LINQ to SQL I think.. I'll add in a work around anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do the function in a LINQ to Entities query... one option:

1) have a byte[] property on the object you are instantiating (ImageInformation) and copy the data in there along with another propery to read the image from this ImageInformation object.